# Why most works on Cityscapes don't use weighted cross-entropy?

Tags: cross-entropy, image-segmentation

Weight Cross-Entroy (WCE) helps to handle an imbalanced dataset, and Cityscapes is quite imbalanced as seen below:

[image]

If we check the [best benchmarks](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/semantic-segmentation-on-cityscapes) on this dataset, most of the works use bare CE as a loss function. I don't get it if there are any special causes that would lead WCE to a worse result for **semantic segmentation** tasks on the **mIoU** evaluation.

I'm especially asking because I'm working in an even higher unbalanced dataset (multi-minority classes on the ratio of 1:1000 to the majority classes) and got very surprised when bare CE outperformed WCE on the mIoU metric.

I found so far that WCE can yield many false positives from minority classes, but beyond that, would there be more reasons for it?

Comment: What issue do you see regular crossentropy having when it comes to imbalanced classes?

Comment: In a highly imbalanced class situation, wouldn't the learning be tendentious to predict only the most dominant classes or generalize badly the minority classes? I mean, that's not why many works use WCE?

Comment: In a highly imbalanced class situation, aren't the dominant classes more likely?

Comment: Do you have any reference or explanation that CE is not an issue in this scenario? B/c my doubt is that I used to see that regular CE was a problem on this, and that's why some works suggested WCE (like U-net paper); Dice, and IoU surrogate losses.

Comment: To get started with probability prediction and how that interacts with class imbalance, I suggest starting with two blog posts by Frank Harrell, founding chair of the Department of Biostatistics and Vanderbilt Medical School: [Post 1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/) [Post 2](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/). These will not directly answer your question, but they will start you down the rabbit hole.